# Java 8 Streams: streaming files and delete after read

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I want to stream the lines contained in files but deleting each file once it has been processed.

The current process is like this:

Explanation:

1. I create a Stream of Files
2. I create a BufferedReader for each one of them
3. I flatMap to the lines Stream of the BufferedReader
4. I print each line.

Code:

```
(1)    Stream.generate(localFileProvider::getNextFile)
(2)       .map(file -> return new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(file))))
(3)       .flatMap(BufferedReader::lines)
(4)       .map(System.out::println);
```

Would it be possible to **delete each file once it has been completely read** and continue processing the other files in the stream?

Thank you!

Comment: Stream has `onClose(Runnable)` method. I didn't try it and write it from top of my head, however I got an idea of `Stream.generate(...).flatMap(file -> new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(file))).lines().onClose(() -> file.delete()))`. Not sure if it is possible, probably for not closing BufferedReader or checked exceptions breaking lambda.

Comment: Can you explain more why you don't want to iterate over each file, stream it's lines, and delete that file? Or do the streaming as you did, and after that delete all files?

Comment: `file -> return …` is not a valid lambda expression. Also, `new FileInputStream(…)` requires you to catch `IOException`. Further, `.map(System.out::println)` is not a valid operation as `println` doesn’t return a value, but you very likely wanted to perform `forEach` instead.

Comment: I want to load the contents of each file that is copied to a specific directory. The answer has been provided, and I made a new question because my scenario is not precise enought: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61914029/java-8-streams-streaming-files-and-moving-them-after-read

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use `flatMap`, the stream returned by the function will get closed automatically, once it has been processed. You only need to add an option when opening the `InputStream`, specifying that its underlying file should get deleted on close.

Assuming that `localFileProvider.getNextFile()` returns a `java.io.File`, the code looks like

```
Stream.generate(localFileProvider::getNextFile)
    .takeWhile(Objects::nonNull) // stop on null, otherwise, it’s an infinite stream

// the actual operation regarding your question:
    .flatMap(file -> {
        try { return new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
            Files.newInputStream(file.toPath(), StandardOpenOption.DELETE_ON_CLOSE)))
            .lines();
        } catch(IOException ex) { throw new UncheckedIOException(ex); }
    })

// the example terminal operation
    .forEach(System.out::println);
```

You need to use [`Files.newInputStream(Path, OpenOption...)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#newInputStream-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.file.OpenOption...-) instead of `new FileInputStream(…)` to specify the special open option. So the code above converts the `File` to a `Path` via `toPath()`; if `getNextFile()` returns a `String`, you would need [`Paths.get(file)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Paths.html#get-java.lang.String-java.lang.String...-) instead.

Comment: Awesome your answer is correct, the funny part is that I don't really want to close the file, I want to rename it, I just said "delete" to simplify, I thought the solution would be the same :D

Comment: I have marked your answer as correct, and I have done a new question with my real scenario: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61914029/java-8-streams-streaming-files-and-moving-them-after-read